# $("selector").find(":psuedo-class") does not return desired elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following declaration:

```
var optionsWithAttribute = $(element).find("option[data-attribute]");
```

I now want to grab the selected options from that set, so I write:

```
var selectedOptions = optionsWithAttribute.find(":selected");
```

However this yields the effective selector:

```
"option[data-attribute] :selected"
```

which obviously matches nothing (thanks to [jquery.whiny](https://github.com/mikeycgto/jquery.whiny.js) for helping me to solve this). The correct selector would be:

```
"option[data-attribute]:selected"
```

(note lack of space after the `]`).

Obviously this is because subsequent calls to `.find()` prepend a space so that (for example) the expression `$("select").find("option")` yields the selector `select option` as opposed to `selectoption`. Either I'm doing something wrong - in which case please educate me - or `.find()` should be changed to not insert a space if the passed-in selector is a pseudo-class (i.e. begins with a colon).

Comment: Use .filter(). This has nothing to do with whether you're using pseudo classes, and no prepending is occurring: the .find() method looks for descendent elements.

Comment: `.find()` adds a space because a space and `.find()` are the same thing.   `$("select").find("option")` says return all `option` elements that are under the `select` element - this is the same as `$("select option")`

Comment: @freedomn-m this maybe out of the OP but can you tell which is better using `.find()` as `$("select").find("option")`  or `$("select option")`

Comment: Use the first if you already have the object, eg `var s = $("select"); s.find("option")`.  Use the second if you have/want it as text.  You can also use `$("option", s);` but many people find that confusing and prefer the `.find` format.

Comment: Wow, now I feel dumb. Thanks all - I knew `.filter()` existed but not that it allowed a selector to be specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use filter as `optionsWithAttribute` contains the `option` elements, `find()` will look for a matching descendant element

```
var selectedOptions = optionsWithAttribute.filter(":selected");
```

Answer (score 2):

`.find()` selects children of the parent element , you need to use `.filter()` which will give you only the items with the select attribute

When you use this code `var selectedOptions = optionsWithAttribute.find(":selected");` jquery will search all the elements with the attribute  selected from the tag options (optionsWithAttribute)

Answer (score 1):

try to use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or
>   pass the function's test.

```
var selectedOptions = optionsWithAttribute.filter(":selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

> "option[data-attribute] :selected"
>   *which obviously matches nothing*

Absolutely because that is incorrect, you can't find selected option inside options, so change it to:

```
var optionsWithAttribute = $(element).find("option[data-attribute]:selected");
console.log(optionsWithAttribute)
```